# Array of strings in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wanna know whether is it possible to store **array of string in the SharedPreferences**. In my application i want , **set of names to be stored**. I know this can be done using DB,i just wanna know whether **is it possible** to save those **set of name as array of strings in the SharedPreferences**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store set of String using `SharedPreferences` in API Level 11 and higher. See [`getStringSet()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) and [`putStringSet()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)ю

In API Level prior to 11 you can use some kind of hack. For example, if you need to store string array under key *"stringArray"*, you can save each string from array using `putString` and keys *"stringArray.1"*, *"stringArray.2"*, so on.

Comment: thanks .... i feel this would definitly help me.But is this good way of storing strings, in general ??  i mean storing set of strings in the shared preferences rather than in DB?

Comment: If you have small array of strings it might be easier to just use `SharedPrefernece`. But if you need large arrays of strings, I'd say DB is the only way to go. Its harder to implement and use, but it would more efficient.

Comment: thank for your suggestion and i found that the SET, data structure ,cannot contain duplicate elements. does it mean that it cannot contain same string more than once?? @inazaruk

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for StringTokenizer then [blog post 1](http://chandan-tech.blogspot.com/2011/05/string-tokenizer-in-java.html) and [blog post2](http://chandan-tech.blogspot.com/2011/05/string-tokenizer-in-java-ii.html) would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to store them as an array, but you can concatenate them, and then split them when loading, using `StringTokenizer`. I can help with some code, if this will be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks.., ya sure.. some links or code regarding this would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

In shared preferences, you can store the data like key value pairs.
What I usually do is to insert all the data then get the key list and iterate through it, set key as anything unique, be it numbers 1,2,3 etc

use

SharedPreference sp = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
Map presetDataMap = sp.getAll();

then loop through presetDataMap,

Iterator itt = presetDataMap.keySet().iterator();

hope this helps.