# Android: How to store array of strings in SharedPreferences for android

Tags: android, search-engine, sharedpreferences, android-browser

I'm building an app which searches the web using search engine. I have one edittext in my app from which user will search the web. I want to save the search keywords just like browser history does. I'm able to save and display it with the last keyword but I can't increase the number of searches result. I want to display the last 5 searhes. Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button insert;
EditText edt;
TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_word);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt1.setOnClickListener(this);

    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((edt.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Whoa! You haven't entered anything in the search box.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                String text = edt.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("key", text);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String text = app_preferences.getString("key", "null");
    txt1.setText(text);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    String text = txt1.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Please help me in overcoming this problem.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761885/array-of-strings-in-sharedpreferences

Comment: I have seen that thing, but that was not helping me, I was not able to put the Strings from that.

Comment: You can use gson to save array http://stackoverflow.com/a/22985657/1577792

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SAVE ARRAY

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
    return editor.commit();  
}
```

LOAD ARRAY

```
public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    String array[] = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. One thing, for saving the Strings array, I'll have to place SAVE ARRAY onClick() and LOAD ARRAY onStart() function. Hope you have seen my code, what I'm trying to do.

Comment: did u get what u wanted? or tell me what exactly u want to do

Comment: onClick I want to store strings from the edittext one by one. And onStart() I have to display the Strings which I have stored.

Comment: so simply use these two methods in onCLick and onStart!!

Comment: Exactly can you tell me how to do that. Because I'm not able to do that.

Comment: Can you tell me how to call above mentioned function on onClick()?

Comment: replace the toast with the above method call ... 
saveArray("//your array name here","the name with u want to store it","//context THIS");

Comment: I'm not getting you, can you please paste the dummy code here, so that I can see what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array or object to Json with Gson library and store your data as String in json format.

Save;

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);

editor.putString(TAG, json);
editor.commit();
```

Read;

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, null);
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayObject>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Original answer: [Storing Array List Object in SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984696/storing-array-list-object-in-sharedpreferences/22985657#22985657)