# Store ArrayList of Objects in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of `String` objects that is keeping values as needed.
now i want to keep it save either as a FILE or in `SharedPreferences` or converting it into `JSON` ARRAY and saving..
  My array list is like this:

```
  ArrayList<Struct_Saved_Domains> arraylist = new ArrayList<Struct_Saved_Domains>();
```

How can i do this? Any Idea??

Comment: check this answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350800/android-how-to-store-array-of-strings-in-sharedpreferences-for-android?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your object into string and then save it in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putStringSet("myList", new Gson().toJson(arraylist).toString());
editor.apply();
```

Comment: How to add the Gson??
Any jar file?

Comment: download the library's jar file and put it inside **libs** folder of your project. If you dont have such folder then create one manually. Afterwards you are ready to go.

Comment: @Waqas.. yeah i got it now.. its included..Thanks

Comment: @Waqas.. Shared pref is not reliable.. like when i exit the app and reload it and try to save new values then the old values are gone.
CAn u suggest me any other way to keep old values in the array and adding new ones ??

Comment: which android API version are you using for your app? if its gingerbread or above then please call `apply()` instead of `commit()` on your preference editor.

Comment: @Waqas.. i had put this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242506/store-arraylist-of-cutom-objects/15242639?noredirect=1#15242639
Got some idea from it :)

Comment: ahh, you had to append the new values in the old one by reading it first. however, if you want to add new entries in the preference storage then simply introduce more new keys like myList1, myList2, myList2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for shared preferences.

```
public class WebService {

    String PREF_NAME = "PREF_NAME";
    public static SharedPreferences sp;
    Editor spEdit;

    public String UserID;
    public String Password;


    public LoginWebService(Context ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-geneated constructor stub
        sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        spEdit = sp.edit();
    }

    public void setUserID(String UserID) {
        spEdit.putString("UserID", UserID);
        spEdit.commit();

    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return sp.getString("UserID", "");    
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return sp.getString("Password", "");
    }

    public void setPassword(String Password) {
        spEdit.putString("Password", Password);
        spEdit.commit();
    }





    public void clear(){
        spEdit.clear();
        spEdit.commit();
    }

}
```

While saving the data in the shared preferences you can use like below.

```
WebService objlogin=new WebService(context);
objlogin.clear();

for (int i = 0; i <arraylist.size(); i++) 
{
objlogin.setUserID(arraylist.get(i).something); 
objlogin.setPassword(arraylist.get(i).something); 

}
```

Then you all the data's will be saved in the shard preferences.

Hope this will help you.