# Store Arraylist of custom objects

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have saved ArrayList of custom objects in the shared preferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putStringSet("myList", new Gson().toJson(arraylist).toString());
editor.apply();
```

By doing this, once values are saved but when i exit from the app and relaunch and try to save new values then the old values are gone.
Any idea how can i save old values and append new ones?
I want to keep all values in the same array and keep array saved to show values every time when the app loads.

Comment: Naturally the old values will be gone.  If you need to append, then you need to read the original ones, append the new ones and save back.

Comment: @AleksG.. okay man i implement this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read `myList` from `prefName`, append `arraylist` to what was already saved in the preferences, write back `myList` to preferences.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be work for you.

```
 SharedPreferences setting=context.getSharedPreferences("prefName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor edit=setting.edit();
 edit.putStringSet("myList", new Gson().toJson(arraylist).toString());
 edit.commit();
```

Comment: whenever you want to change the value put this code in method. call that method once again.

Comment: I would really like to know who upvoted this answer because it does nothing but replace `apply()` by `commit()` which is definitely _not_ the cause of the problem here. Quite to the contrary, it could even create a performance hit on the UI thread.

Comment: I am already doing it man.. Its just saving the things into prefs... Please read my question again.

Comment: Get that listArray and append the **new value** in the list then after store it in shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

I hav faced this problem earlier... Use generics it will append the value rather than replacing the old datas....

Comment: @Noman Kindly read how to use generics in java.. It may be useful for your future problems...