# How to store color value in SharedMemory?

Tags: android

I am writing a simple program which involves color changing of certain elements.
For color changing, I have to store the color value (which I get from the color picker) in the SharedMemory. I have the following color picker code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener {

    private ColorPicker picker;
    private SVBar svBar;
    private OpacityBar opacityBar;
    private Button button;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        picker = (ColorPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
        svBar = (SVBar) findViewById(R.id.svbar);
        opacityBar = (OpacityBar) findViewById(R.id.opacitybar);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        picker.addSVBar(svBar);
        picker.addOpacityBar(opacityBar);
        picker.setOnColorChangedListener(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("Color",""+ picker.getColor());
                text.setTextColor(picker.getColor());
                picker.setOldCenterColor(picker.getColor());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onColorChanged(int color) {
        //gives the color when it's changed.
    }
}
```

How can I store the value of **picker.getColor()** in the SharedMemory?

Comment: you have to set text color like. after getting int value from shared preference you just need to use yourTextView.setTextColor(color);

Comment: didn't get you anything from this?

Comment: I am trying to understand this But I am not getting it. :(

Comment: You have to store it using Shared Preference.

Comment: Yes..But I am not getting the code...I am trying   Utils.readPreferences(MainActivity.this, "colorKey", 0) But how to change the value using it ?

Comment: Okay. So r u working with demo project or in live?

Comment: I am working on a Live Project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51864/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-miss-noob)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override 
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mycolor), color);
    editor.commit();
}
```

To get the stored color from Shared Preference use this

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int storedColor = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.mycolor), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

User SharedPreference to store your color value.

Shared preference is place where you can store data that persist till the time app exists on device and if user does not clear the app memory through settings.

If you want to store array of colors,refer this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350878/2035885

If just a single value needs to be stored, refer below:

```
public static int getColor(Context context)
{
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("your_shared_preference_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sharedPreference.getInt("key_to_use_to_set_and_retrieve_value", 0);
}


public static void setColor(Context context,int color)
{
SharedPreferences store = context.getSharedPreferences(MenuActivity.class.getSimpleName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = store.edit();
edit.putInt("key_to_use_to_set_and_retrieve_value", color);
edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it as an `int`. That's already what it is.

```
@Override 
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    // omitted: get a SharedPreferences object first
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("color", color).apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

//Set To SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourSharePreferenceName", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putInt("pickerColor",picker.getColor() );
  editor.commit();

//Get From SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourSharePreferenceName", MODE_PRIVATE);
  picker.setOldCenterColor(sharedPreferences.getInt("pickerColor",0));
```

Answer (score 0):

java was follows

```
package com.example.sharedpreferenceexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Utils {

    public static void savePreferences(Activity activity, String key1,
            int value1) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = sp.edit();

        editor.putInt(key1, value1);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public static int readPreferences(Activity activity, String key,
            int defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        return sp.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

to save

```
Utils.savePreferences(MainActivity.this, "colorKey", colorValue);
```

to read

```
 Utils.readPreferences(MainActivity.this, "colorKey", 0)
```